# «Обычай деспот меж людей». Почему нет тире?

Tags: пунктуация, тире, пушкин

*Быть можно дельным человеком

И думать о красе ногтей:

К чему бесплодно спорить с веком?

**Обычай деспот меж людей**.*
А. С. Пушкин

Почему нет тире между подлежащим и сказуемым в форме И. п.?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

В толковом словаре Ушакова (1935-1940):
[ОБЫЧАЙ](https://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/ushakov/897466/%D0%9E%D0%91%D0%AB%D0%A7%D0%90%D0%99)
*Обычай — деспот меж людей*.

В энциклопедическом словаре крылатых слов и выражений (автор-составитель В. Серов):
[Обычай — деспот меж людей](http://www.bibliotekar.ru/encSlov/14/47.htm)
Из романа в стихах «Евгений Онегин» (1823—1831) А. С. Пушкина (1799-1837) (гл. 1, строфа 25).
*К чему бесплодно спорить с веком? Обычай — деспот меж людей.*
Смысл выражения: правила, некогда установленные людьми, со временем становятся неписаными законами, которым приходится подчиняться — вопреки здравому смыслу и собственным интересам.

В энциклопедии народной мудрости (Н. Уваров):
[Обычай — лучший толкователь закона.](https://books.google.ee/books?id=WJniBAAAQBAJ&pg=PT1131&lpg=PT1131&dq=%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5%20%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%8B%D1%87%D0%B0%D0%B8%20%E2%80%94%20%D0%BB%D1%83%D1%87%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%B5&source=bl&ots=Mbvp9FBpmi&sig=7GsicptTFxFEcxRCwNxIb177Dac&hl=ru&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjiuOzH7a7eAhULkCwKHcxsBNg4ChDoATAJegQIAxAB#v=onepage&q=%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5%20%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%8B%D1%87%D0%B0%D0%B8%20%E2%80%94%20%D0%BB%D1%83%D1%87%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%B5&f=false)

Думаю, что по современным правилам тире необходимо.
В отдельных словарных статьях, где не требуется полное цитирование, а также при использовании предложения как фразеологизма ([Афоризмы про обычай](http://stuki-druki.com/aforizm_Obichay.php)), оно присутствует.

Comment: Спасибо, но  разве тире ставится во всех  изданиях романа. Я посмотрела в Интернете  несколько вариантов, но тире в них нет.

Comment: В случае **цитирования** всего четверостишия тире нет (мне не встретилось), а вот фразеологизм, употребляемый сегодня — в отрыве от собственно имени Пушкина, — требует современной пунктуации, то есть присутствия тире.

Comment: Так почему у Пушкина нет тире? Когда мы используем пушкинскую фразу в качестве афоризма в повествовательной речи, то тире ставится. Может быть,  дело не в правилах, а  просто этот знак  не вписывается в ритмику стиха? Ведь нельзя сказать, что Пушкин тире вообще в таких конструкциях не ставил. Например: Замечу кстати: все поэты — Любви мечтательной друзья.

Answer (score 2):

Здесь уже был похожий вопрос по пушкинскому тексту. Тоже по поводу отсутствия тире между подлежащим и сказуемым. Видимо, Александр Сергеевич не любил ставить тире в подобных случаях - даже в прозе, а в стихах и подавно. А что говорили об этом правила почти двести лет назад - надо серьезно изучать.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Скажите, пожалуйста,  а в современном стихотворном тексте Вы бы поставили в этом предложении тире? И если нет, то почему?

Comment: По правилам тире должно быть. Это не зависит от того, стихотворный текст или прозаический. Предложение есть предложение.